# WebSite - download link

Tags: html, download, file-access

I'm just playing around with HTML, and wanted to create a link to access a file in a particular location on the disk (not on the disk where the source code of the web page is located).

I have tried to do the following:

`<a href="D:\MyDoc.pdf">Download My File</a>`

but this cannot access the file and gives an error.

What can be the problem, and how do I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: What error? How do you deploy this HTML? Can the browser you open it in access the file on you local disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work!  Just add file:/// in the link URL

```
<a href="file:///D:\MyDoc.pdf">Download My File</a>
```

This will only work if you run the Application offline.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it did not work, as I host this using glassfish, so knowing IP, other people could access it (I did from another computer anyway =))

Comment: What are you trying you do? Give me more detail on what you are build and how you need it to work?

Comment: I have just started to learn HTML and other languages used to create websites.

Here is what I need to do:
1) Host a website on my computer and access it from Internet (My computer is using wireless and also, and I'm using this particular computer as a desktop)
2) Be able to download stuff from a particular location on my machine by specifying path to it (Ex. D:\My Documents\MyDoc.pdf)
3) If you can tell me about FTP a bit, I will appreciate it.

Why? For the hell of it =)))) Thanks!

Comment: You can set up a Webserver on your own computer using Xampp. This will allow you to serve HTML files to the internet.  It requires forwarding port on your router - http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html

Comment: Also XAMPP uses filezila which will let you download file from other Computer accessing it from the internet.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much! 

Was wondering - what motivates people (including yourself) to answer all of those questions? Reputation you gain?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can do this with pure html. You will need to use a dynamic web technology such as php or Asp.net.

Can you imagine the security issues if you could download any file you wanted off the web server just by changing path of that link?

Comment: Well, it works, if the file is located within the directory of the source web page. I can download the file even from another computer (It's accessible as I have glassfish running). But yeah, I definitely agree about security issues. Will keep on digging and checking it out.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't place the file into the web site directory? IIS lets you create virtual directories so that you could have D:\MyDocs\ mounted as http://www.yourwebsite.com/MyDocs/ I'm not sure if Glassfish has this feature but it seems likely.

Another option is if you are running this only on a local network you could make the file available on the local network and use something like '<a href="\\computername\sharename\MyDoc.pdf">Download</a>'

Comment: No, I was just playing around with it, and thought that it would be nice if I could access files on my from outside. I also want to learn how ftp works? so this was the first step =) Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it.